# subversion tag of a collection of directories

Tags: svn, tagging

In my working space, I have a directory "working" that contains a set of directories all taken from the same SVN repo (dir1, dir2, dir3).  I would like to tag all of them by doing:

```
   cd working
   svn copy dir1 dir2 dir3 http://svn.example.com/repos/project/tags/MY_TAG
```

The "working" directory is not itself versioned in SVN.  I want to get dir1, dir2, dir3 at whatever SVN version they are currently at (which may not be HEAD from the trunk).  When I try this, I get the error:

```
   svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

"svn help copy" and [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html#svn.branchmerge.tags.mksimple) both suggest that what I'm doing should be possible, but I guess the fact that "working" is not itself versioned precludes this.

TIA for suggestions on how to do this.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Checkout into new WC parent of dir* (HEAD, fully recursive) and tag **this** WC

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't really what I want -- the parent of dir* contains lots of directories, and I only want the subset dir1, dir2, dir3, and I only want to tag these three dirs, and not all the other ones.

Comment: Well, you know - you want something against rules and patterns?! Tag (branch) is always fixed state of full repo, not subset. But - create full copy, remove unwanted content (dirs and files), commit thin result, tag *this subset*